# Is there a constant for this?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}=1$, where $\lambda_{i}>0$,
and $\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2}=1$, where $x_{i}>0$. Does one have
$n^{3/2}\min_{1\le i\le n}\lambda_{i}x_{i}\le B$ for some constant
$B$ (independent of $n$)? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The largest $\min_i \lambda_i x_i$ can be is when all $\lambda_i = 1/n$ and all $x_i = 1/\sqrt{n}$, which makes the left side $1$.

Comment: Robert, thank you for your answer, but can you exaplain why the largest is that in your answer? Thanks.

Comment: It's easy to see that to maximize the minimum, you want to make all $\lambda_i x_i$ equal.  Now if all $\lambda_i x_i = t$ so $x_i = t/\lambda_i$, we have $1 = \sum_i x_i^2 = t^2 \sum_i 1/\lambda_i^2$.  Since $f(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n) = \sum_i 1/\lambda_i^2$ is a convex function and symmetric in $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n$, by averaging over cyclic permutations we get $$f\left(\frac{\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n}{n}, \ldots, \frac{\lambda_1 + \ldots + \lambda_n}{n}\right) \le f(\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n)$$

Comment: Dear Robert, just one thing, why does the maximum occur when all $\lambda_ix_i$ equal? Thanks a lot!

Comment: If, say, $\lambda_1 x_1 < \lambda_2 x_2$, then you increase the minimum by increasing $\lambda_1$ and $x_1$ slightly while decreasing $\lambda_2$ and $x_2$ to keep $\lambda_1 + \lambda_2$ and $x_1^2 + x_2^2$ constant.

Comment: Dear Robert, what you just said shows the local maximum occurs there, but why does the global maximum also occur there? Thanks a lot again!

Comment: A continuous function on a compact set attains a maximum (to get a compact set, you have to change $>0$ to $\ge 0$, but the value is $0$ when some $\lambda_i$ or $x_i$ is $0$).